# How can I run an if/else Javascript function through and input field and a button as the event in HTML?

Tags: javascript, function, dom, event-handling, getelementbyid

I have a javascript function that I want to connect to and run through my HTML. It’s a simple function that shows an answer (most popular video game) based on the year entered. Now my idea is that this input is passed through an input field in the HTML and the answer appears after a button click as an event. My problem is that I can’t connect this function to my HTML through the input field. in other words, function is ready but I can’t run/apply it still. I have been trying and experimenting with DOM but I keep getting more lost.

In other words, I have the Javascript and and the HTML for what I want to show but there’s a missing step, the HTML code that refers to and actually run the javascript code.

here's the beginning and end of the function for convenience since it starts from the the year 1950 till 2020;

```
mostPopularGame = year => {

const submitBtn = document.getElementById("yearInput");

if (year <= 0 || year > 2020 ) {
return 'Please enter a valid year!'
} else if ( year >= 1950 && year <= 1970) {
return 'Starting 1950 till 1969, early computer games on which everything we play now is based were developed as a hobby on university mainframe computers.'
} else if ( year === 1971 ) {
  return 'The most popular video game that year was Computer Space'
else {
return 'please enter a year starting 1950'
}
};
```

Now this is my HTML, I'm aware there is code missing and that it might look a little confusing (sorry for that) since I'm a little bit lost when it comes to DOM, event handlers and event listeners. I have been trying to get it done for 4 days but I removed the code that I suspected wouldn't help. As you can see, my code is inside a form that includes a text input field for years and another input as a button for the event.

```
<form>
          <h2> Please enter year here </h2>
         
      <input id="yearInput" type="text"/>
            <p> </p>
            
            <input type="button" id="result"
                   value="check"
                   onclick="mostPopularGame()">
                   </form>
```

Sorry for the long question but I'm quite desperate for an answer to this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your `return` to the `onclick` is useless. You need to do something that displays the result from inside your function. What is the expected behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i understood you well  then you had to do something like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <h2> Please enter year here </h2>

    <input id="yearInput" type="text" />
    <p> </p>

    <input type="button" id="result" value="check" onclick="notify()">
  </form>
  <script>
    mostPopularGame = () => {

      const submitBtn = document.getElementById("yearInput");
      let year = submitBtn.value
      if (year <= 0 || year > 2020) {
        return 'Please enter a valid year!'
      } else if (year >= 1950 && year <= 1970) {
        return 'Starting 1950 till 1969, early computer games on which everything we play now is based were developed as a hobby on university mainframe computers.'
      } else if (year === 1971) {
        return 'The most popular video game that year was Computer Space'
      } else {
        return 'please enter a year starting 1950'
      }
    };

    notify = () => {
      alert(mostPopularGame())
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It successfully ran. Thank you! my initial goal was to return the result in the empty **p** tag but that was the easier part, I figured that out. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking to get the value from the input field. You almost have it.

You use getElementById to get the element. Part of the element's object is .value.

```
function mostPopularGame() {

    let year = document.getElementById("yearInput").value; // Gets #yearInput's value

    if (year <= 0 || year > 2020 ) {
       results =  'Please enter a valid year!'
    } else if ( year >= 1950 && year <= 1970) {
       results =  'Starting 1950 till 1969, early computer games on which everything we play now 
               is based were developed as a hobby on university mainframe computers.'
    } else if ( year === 1971 ) {
       results =  'The most popular video game that year was Computer Space'
    } else {
       results = 'please enter a year starting 1950'
    }

    document.getElementById("#results").innerText = results;
};
```

HTML:

```
    <form>
        <h2> Please enter year here </h2>
         
        <input id="yearInput" type="text"/>
        <p id="results"></p>
            
        <input type="button" id="result" value="check" onclick="mostPopularGame()">
     </form>
```

Comment: What is going to happen with the `return`?

Comment: It'll return the string. I'd recommend you change the return to `results = "Your message"` and then at the end of the function do `document.getElementById("#results").innerText = result`

Comment: I am not the one who asked the initial code question. My comment was intended for you to be able to actually clarify your answer since it is not valid. You can edit the answer at any time to fix bugs, clarify etc. As it currently stands your answer is not usable which defeats the whole purpose of this site

Comment: My original answer was to answer his question. "How can I run an if/else Javascript function through [an] input field.." Nothing stated about a return or displaying the results. There was very little indication of what he wanted to do after the input. I see he later commented saying that the <p> tag would hold the returns. I didn't want to assume. I just wanted to answer his question. I have changed my answer to include further indication.

Comment: No matter wht OP was looking for, a `return` of a string in the event handler is useless. Pointing out such irregularities is part of providing constructive answers. Please don't take these comments as criticism but rather as constructive

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you had an empty **p** tag, so I'm assuming you want to return the result into here.

```js
mostPopularGame = (year) => {
  /* Get user's input */
  var year = document.getElementById("yearInput").value;

  /* Default result */
  var result = "please enter a year starting 1950";

  /* Compare integer */
  if (year <= 0 || year > 2020) {
    result = "Please enter a valid year!";
  } else if (year >= 1950 && year <= 1970) {
    result = "Starting 1950 till 1969, early computer games on which everything we play now is based were developed as a hobby on university mainframe computers.";
  } else if (year === 1971) {
    result = "The most popular video game that year was Computer Space";
  }
  
  /* Render result to p element */
  document.getElementById('result').innerText = result;
};
```

```html
<form>
  <h2> Please enter year here </h2>

  <input id="yearInput" type="number" />
  <p id="result"></p>

  <input type="button" id="result" value="check" onclick="mostPopularGame()">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I indeed wanted to return the result in the **p** tag. Unfortunately, the code didn't run when I tried it, didn't return any results. I also tried to return it as an alert with no luck.

Thanks again.

Comment: Hi @AhmadMagdy. The code runs fine for me. Do you mean it didn't run on here (code snippet), or at your end? Please make sure to update your HTML as well please, I've added a ID to the P tag.

Comment: Hey @ActiveCodex 
It was a mistake on my end in the HTML code. It successfully runs now and it shows the result in my **p** tag. 

As I understand, you set the return as a variable/s (=result) and referred to it in the HTML. Is that correct? It was new to know that declaring a default result as a variable (Var result =) makes up for ending the function with an else statement. 

Thanks for your time, man. Appreciated.